# When writing code for a TCP socket server, what's the best library (C/C++) to use for multiple asynchronous connections?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I'm writing C/C++ code for a TCP Socket Server that will be running on a Windows machine.  I've come across the Winsock library but I'm wondering whether or not it is good enough to handle, say 100-150 simultaneous connections.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You mean the Winsock that's a part of Windows and handles everything that's going on in the network world for tens of thousands of concurrent connections?

Comment: These kind of questions are explicitly _off-topic_ here. Read point #4 from this [help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'd recommend using `boost::asio` though.

Comment: Your question is too broad and is against Stack Overflow's guidelines on how to ask a question. They don't like "What library for" questions as they become opinionated. So, it's likely to get closed. That said, most people I've encountered are using Boost::ASIO these days. It does Windows IO completion ports under the covers, but is a lot easier to use compared to straight Winsock.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Winsock is the socket library on Windows. Any C++ library on Windows for networking internally calls Winsock only.

However, Winsock is a C library.

Scalability. First of all, yes it can scale up to thousands of concurrent connections. Second, for scalability you would require asynchronous sockets. There are many techniques to do this like, Scatter/Gather I/O (look for Winsock functions prefixed with WSA), ioctls to name the common choices.

You may also like to explore boost:asio. It is pure C++, easier syntax.

Answer (score -1):

WinSock IS the TCP stack on Windows, so, yes, it can handle as many connections as you can throw at it.

There are some wrappers around this (such as Alhem), which make writing applications easier, but it still uses WinSock.